# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function. Trying to use useContext

Tags: react-native

I've got the following class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './Login.styles'
import { AuthContext } from '../../../context';



    export default class Login extends React.Component {
        state={
            email:"",
            password:""
        }
        
        render() {
        
        const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.logo}>Bienvenido :)</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() => signIn()}>
                    <Text style={styles.inText}>Ingresar</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> 
        );
    }
}
```

I'm aware the problem is at the line where I define const { signIn } but my problem is I don't know how to fix this.

AuthContext looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

Any ideas? I know this is a common issue and I've read plenty of other similar questions but I have no clue how to make them work on my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use hooks inside a React Class Component.

If you wish to use the `useContext()` hook, you will need to refactor your component as a functional component. e.g.

```
export default function Login() {
  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const [email, setEmail]  = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.logo}>Bienvenido :)</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() => signIn()}>
        <Text style={styles.inText}>Ingresar</Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
  )
```

Comment: I'm aware but my question is aiming to how can I invoke useContext inside my class when that button is pressed.